# read a Binary image

Tags: java, android, binary

I've got my socket communication up and running.

I now need help with the following:

We are going to send a image to the device through the socket.

```
transmit.framebuffer.rgb_byte will transmit in binary format the following information:
[4 bytes] => image width
[4 bytes] => image height
[< image width> * <image height> * 3 bytes] => RGB in unsigned char format [0, 255]
[3 bytes] "OK\n"
```

How would I go about getting this to work?..
For now I've just worked with plain text etc,
so this whole binary coding is new to me.

Comment: What's the problem? Use (Buffered)InputStream/(Buffered)OutputStream, and write the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of you could read data on the client side:

```
out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024 * 16];
int size = 0;
while ((size = in.read(dataBuffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(dataBuffer, 0, size);
}
out.flush();
byte[] bytesReceived = out.toByteArray();
```

Comment: thank you. just need to get my head wrapped around this.
How can i proceed to insert the grabbed data into a picturebox?

Comment: I need to say that something sounds odd. Why isn't the server sending an image in a valid image format? E.g. a png or jpg. It would then be a lot easier to display the image.

Comment: Looks like you could convert the byte[] to an array of integers instead (where you need to OR and shift 3 bytes into one integer) and then use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[], int, int, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)

Comment: I cannot answer your question as to why, because I'm not writing that part of it.. I might thought - ask for a different solution after I've tried this. I know the system can save as png file, would it be easier to send the file itself in some way?

Thank you for the help and explanation so far.

Comment: It would be better to use standard image format instead of your own. You could leverage existing API, with a solid, optimized and nearly bug free code. But this seems to be some sort of project or homework, so maybe the reason is just to make you learn how one could store an image in binary format.

Comment: I too think it would be best, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @hedphelym. Yes it would be much easier to send the original file since you then only will send compressed data (most images are compressed in some way)